# Format a text in javascript which contains recurring blocks of text with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a text containing recurring blocks of same structured texts which are as follows:

```html
From marvin.seegers@gmail.com Fri Aug 11 10:35:14 2017 Return-Path:
<crowdwiggel@n1plcpnl0114.prod.ams1.secureserver.net>
  Delivered-To: buchung@think-square.de Received: from n1plcpnl0114.prod.ams1.secureserver.net by n1plcpnl0114.prod.ams1.secureserver.net (Dovecot) with LMTP id CdUzIUJsjVleYAQAtX1LSA for
  <buchung@think-square.de>; Fri, 11 Aug 2017 01:35:14 -0700 Return-path:
    <crowdwiggel@n1plcpnl0114.prod.ams1.secureserver.net>
      Envelope-to: buchung@think-square.de Delivery-date: Fri, 11 Aug 2017 01:35:14 -0700 Received: from crowdwiggel by n1plcpnl0114.prod.ams1.secureserver.net with local (Exim 4.88) (envelope-from
      <crowdwiggel@n1plcpnl0114.prod.ams1.secureserver.net>) id 1dg5PW-001Eda-Ep for buchung@think-square.de; Fri, 11 Aug 2017 01:35:14 -0700 To: buchung@think-square.de Subject: You received a booking request. X-PHP-Script: www.think-square.de/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php for 79.230.85.192 Date: Fri, 11 Aug
        2017 08:35:14 +0000 From: "marvin.seegers@gmail.com"
        <marvin.seegers@gmail.com>
          Reply-To: "marvin.seegers@gmail.com"
          <marvin.seegers@gmail.com>
            Message-ID:
            <e65b7055255651bc19d658f155d8bc7c@www.think-square.de>
              X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.22 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) MIME-Version: 1.1 MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Below are the details. Go to admin to cancel the request.=0A<br
              /><br />=0A=
              <h3>Details</h3>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td style=3D "vertical-align: to=
p; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D "color: #898989;">Reservierungsnummer</st=
rong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=3D"color: #66=
6666;">1952</em></td></tr><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width:=
 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Kalender</strong></td>
                    <td s=t yle=3D "vertical-align: top;"><span style=3D "color: #666666;">7</em></td></=
tr><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=
=3D"color: #898989;">Escape Room</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-al=
ign: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;">Triaden</em></td></tr><tr>     <=
td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #89=
8989;">Gew=C3=A4hlte Sprache</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align:=
 top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;">German (Deutsch)</em></td></tr>     =
</tbody></table><br /><table>     <tbody><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-ali=
gn: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Anreise</strong><=
/td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;"=
>23 September 2017</em></td></tr><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;=
 width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Start um</strong></td>   =
  <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;">20:30<=
/em></td></tr>     </tbody></table><br /><table>     <tbody><tr>     <td st=
yle=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;=
">Zahlungsmethode</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><spa=
n style=3D"color: #666666;">On arrival</em></td></tr><tr>     <td style=3D"=
vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #252525;">Summe=
</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><strong style=3D"colo=
r: #ff6300;">110&#8364;</strong></td></tr>     </tbody></table>=0A<br /><br=
 />=0A<h3>Auswahl</h3><table>     <tbody><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-ali=
gn: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Gruppengr=C3=
=B6=C3=9Fe</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=
=3D"color: #666666;">5 Personen<br /><strong>+&nbsp;110&#8364;</strong></em=
></td></tr><br /><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;">=
<strong style=3D"color: #252525;">Gesamtbetrag</strong></td>     <td style=
=3D"vertical-align: top;"><strong style=3D"color: #252525;">+&nbsp;110&#836=
4;</strong></td></tr>     </tbody></table>=0A<br /><br />=0A<h3>Discount</h=
3><em>No discount.</em>=0A<br /><br />=0A<h3>Coupons</h3><em>No coupon.</em=
>=0A<br /><br />=0A<h3>Taxes & fees</h3><em>No taxes or fees.</em>=0A<br />=
<br />=0A<h3><center><b>Kontaktinformationen</b></center></h3><table>     <=
tbody><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong sty=
le=3D"color: #898989;">Vorname</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-alig=
n: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;">Marvin</em></td></tr><tr>     <td =
style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #89898=
9;">Nachname</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span sty=
le=3D"color: #666666;">Seegers</em></td></tr><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical=
-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Email</strong=
></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666=
;"><a href=3D"mailto:marvin.seegers@gmail.com">marvin.seegers@gmail.com</a>=
</em></td></tr><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><s=
trong style=3D"color: #898989;">Telefon</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vert=
ical-align: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;">01726327217</em></td></tr=
><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D=
"color: #898989;">Gutscheincode (bitte Zahlung vor Ort ausw=C3=A4hlen)</str=
ong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><em style=3D"color: #acaca=
c;">Form field was not completed.</em></td></tr><tr>     <td style=3D"verti=
cal-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Nachricht<=
/strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=3D"color: =
#666666;">Hey!=0AIch w=C3=BCrde den Abend gerne meinen Geburtstag bei euch =
nachfeiern.=0A=0AGr=C3=BC=C3=9Fe</em></td></tr><tr>     <td style=3D"vertic=
al-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Wie habe ic=
h von Think Square erfahren</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: =
top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;">Google</em></td></tr>     </tbody></t=
able>=0A<br /><br />=0A<h3>Billing address</h3><table>     <tbody><em>No bi=
lling address.</em>     </tbody></table>=0A<br /><br />=0A<h3>Shipping addr=
ess</h3><table>     <tbody><em>No shipping address.</em>     </tbody></tabl=
e>

From katharina.lensing@hotmail.de Fri Aug 11 07:36:47 2017
Return-Path: <crowdwiggel@n1plcpnl0114.prod.ams1.secureserver.net>
Delivered-To: buchung@think-square.de
Received: from n1plcpnl0114.prod.ams1.secureserver.net
 by n1plcpnl0114.prod.ams1.secureserver.net (Dovecot) with LMTP id iVh0Cm9CjVmsaAAAtX1LSA
 for <buchung@think-square.de>; Thu, 10 Aug 2017 22:36:47 -0700
Return-path: <crowdwiggel@n1plcpnl0114.prod.ams1.secureserver.net>
Envelope-to: buchung@think-square.de
Delivery-date: Thu, 10 Aug 2017 22:36:47 -0700
Received: from crowdwiggel by n1plcpnl0114.prod.ams1.secureserver.net with local (Exim 4.88)
 (envelope-from <crowdwiggel@n1plcpnl0114.prod.ams1.secureserver.net>)
 id 1dg2cp-00082R-2s
 for buchung@think-square.de; Thu, 10 Aug 2017 22:36:47 -0700
To: buchung@think-square.de
Subject: You received a booking request.
X-PHP-Script: www.think-square.de/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php for 91.56.142.96
Date: Fri, 11 Aug 2017 05:36:46 +0000
From: "katharina.lensing@hotmail.de" <katharina.lensing@hotmail.de>
Reply-To: "katharina.lensing@hotmail.de" <katharina.lensing@hotmail.de>
Message-ID: <a6cbfd346364029b8055f58d18ac4d89@www.think-square.de>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.22 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Below are the details. Go to admin to cancel the request.=0A<br /><br />=0A=
<h3>Details</h3><table>     <tbody><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: to=
p; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Reservierungsnummer</st=
rong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=3D"color: #66=
6666;">1951</em></td></tr><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width:=
 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Kalender</strong></td>     <td s=
tyle=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;">4</em></td></=
tr><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=
=3D"color: #898989;">Escape Room</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-al=
ign: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;">Contagious</em></td></tr><tr>   =
  <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: =
#898989;">Gew=C3=A4hlte Sprache</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-ali=
gn: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;">German (Deutsch)</em></td></tr>  =
   </tbody></table><br /><table>     <tbody><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-=
align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Anreise</stron=
g></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=3D"color: #66666=
6;">11 August 2017</em></td></tr><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;=
 width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Start um</strong></td>   =
  <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;">19:00<=
/em></td></tr>     </tbody></table><br /><table>     <tbody><tr>     <td st=
yle=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;=
">Zahlungsmethode</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><spa=
n style=3D"color: #666666;">On arrival</em></td></tr><tr>     <td style=3D"=
vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #252525;">Summe=
</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><strong style=3D"colo=
r: #ff6300;">110&#8364;</strong></td></tr>     </tbody></table>=0A<br /><br=
 />=0A<h3>Auswahl</h3><table>     <tbody><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-ali=
gn: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Gruppengr=C3=
=B6=C3=9Fe</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=
=3D"color: #666666;">5 Personen<br /><strong>+&nbsp;110&#8364;</strong></em=
></td></tr><br /><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;">=
<strong style=3D"color: #252525;">Gesamtbetrag</strong></td>     <td style=
=3D"vertical-align: top;"><strong style=3D"color: #252525;">+&nbsp;110&#836=
4;</strong></td></tr>     </tbody></table>=0A<br /><br />=0A<h3>Discount</h=
3><em>No discount.</em>=0A<br /><br />=0A<h3>Coupons</h3><em>No coupon.</em=
>=0A<br /><br />=0A<h3>Taxes & fees</h3><em>No taxes or fees.</em>=0A<br />=
<br />=0A<h3><center><b>Kontaktinformationen</b></center></h3><table>     <=
tbody><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong sty=
le=3D"color: #898989;">Vorname</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-alig=
n: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;">Katharina</em></td></tr><tr>     <=
td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #89=
8989;">Nachname</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span =
style=3D"color: #666666;">Lensing</em></td></tr><tr>     <td style=3D"verti=
cal-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Email</str=
ong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666=
666;"><a href=3D"mailto:katharina.lensing@hotmail.de">katharina.lensing@hot=
mail.de</a></em></td></tr><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width:=
 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #898989;">Telefon</strong></td>     <td st=
yle=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;">01637908883</e=
m></td></tr><tr>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><stro=
ng style=3D"color: #898989;">Gutscheincode (bitte Zahlung vor Ort ausw=
=C3=A4hlen)</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><em style=
=3D"color: #acacac;">Form field was not completed.</em></td></tr><tr>     <=
td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color: #89=
8989;">Nachricht</strong></td>     <td style=3D"vertical-align: top;"><em s=
tyle=3D"color: #acacac;">Form field was not completed.</em></td></tr><tr>  =
   <td style=3D"vertical-align: top; width: 150px;"><strong style=3D"color:=
 #898989;">Wie habe ich von Think Square erfahren</strong></td>     <td sty=
le=3D"vertical-align: top;"><span style=3D"color: #666666;">Google</em></td=
></tr>     </tbody></table>=0A<br /><br />=0A<h3>Billing address</h3><table=
>     <tbody><em>No billing address.</em>     </tbody></table>=0A<br /><br =
/>=0A<h3>Shipping address</h3><table>     <tbody><em>No shipping address.</=
em>     </tbody></table>
```

I am willing to separate a block of text starting from "From" and ending in before beginning of other From. 
I have tried so far

```
var subStr = srctext.match("From (.*) From");

var re = /(.*From\s+)(.*)(\s+From.*)/;
var newtext = srctext.replace(re, "$2");
```

and some variations of regex above but no luck yet

Comment: Do you want only the first block between two `From` or are you trying to retrieve all blocks in an array?

Comment: my plan is to retrieve all blocks and push them into an array to analyse later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.prototype.split` instead:

```
var newtext = srctext.split(/(?:\n|^)From\s+/);
```

`newtext[1]` will contain Marvin's email, `newtext[2]` Katharina's.

`(?:\n|^)From` translates to: "*From* after a newline or a at the beginning of the text".

Tested [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cnb3d7dc/) with a shortened input text.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex:

```
From ([\s\S]*) From
```